How to load Java class with Class.forName() in Android app?
I hava an Android app and want to invoke a Java class, e.g.,
com.example.ThatClass
during runtime (intead of adding the Java class into my app project at compile time).
In the traditional Java development, I can do so by calling something like
Class.forName("com.example.ThatClass")
in my own Java program, when running my program, I just do something like this when running my Java program  java -cp .;ThatClass.jar MyProgram, (ThatClass.jar contains com.example.ThatClass.
But I don't know how this can be done in Android app: like how to tell the app the class path of com.example.ThatClass? Assuming I can place the jar file containing com.example.ThatClass into some system partition when I build the entire AOSP from ground up (so the .jar is a system lib like framework.jar), what is my options?
Thanks!
I tried Google "how to dynamically load java class in Android", but the results show the solution of adding .jar to my app project in Android Studio, this is not what I wanted.

"provide the class path... (or the .jar file if the class is packed into jar)" - is not accurate, you provide only the fully qualified class name (neither a "path" nor a ".jar file") -- actually it is the binary name of the class according the documentation

(the JAR containing the class must be on the class path or a dedicated class loader must be used (e.g. URLClassLoader) )

@user85421 Thanks for pointing this out. What I meant is the -cp argument in "java -cp .;ThatClass.jar MyProgram". This is on the traidiontal Java side, I am wondering what is the counterpart at Android app side.

Please note that this technique is not allowed on the Play Store, loading native code at runtime is a bannable offense.  If this is a personal app go right ahead.

And the correct way to do this even at runtime isn't to do it via java command lines, it's to use a ClassLoader https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html.  The other way may work but it's of limited use.  And won't work on ANdroid because you aren't invoking the interpreter via command line

@GabeSechan, The Android OS is customized, there is no Google Play on it at all.

In that case you can use dynamic loading, but your best bet to use it is via DexClassLoader, which loads files from a dex class at a given location.
